# Sum 1 type in 3D array

Tags: javascript

I cant figure out how to sum only 1 part of my 3D array.

Lets say this is my array, how can I only sum the total amount of the type price?

```
0: {Type: "Food", Price: "100"}
1: {Type: "Entertainment",  Price: "200"}
```

I want to be able to sum the part of the array and get a total of 300.

Comment: what you are quoting is not a 3d array, it is 1d array of objects mostly, can you elaborate more

Comment: `total amount of the type price`? there's no type `Price` in you example. you want to calculate sum of prices of unique types?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the 3D array? If you have an array with this shape `[{Type: "Food", Price: "100"}, {Type: "Entertainment", Price: "200"}]`, you can do this:

```js
const arr = [{Type: "Food", Price: "100"}, {Type: "Entertainment", Price: "200"}];

const sum = arr.map(item => item.Price).reduce((sum, value) => sum + +value, 0);

console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
considering following array, you can achieve 300 sum by this code
```

```js
const array = [
    { Type: "Food", Price: "100" },
    { Type: "Entertainment", Price: "200" }
];

const sumOfPrices = array.reduce((sum, element) => (sum + +element.Price), 0);

console.log(sumOfPrices);
```